# Where do I get GridLayoutManager

Tags: xamarin, android-support-library, gridlayoutmanager

I have a package Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat in my Xamarin Studio.

Is this the package that holding the GridLayoutManager or some other package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope! GridLayoutManager is in [Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView/23.2.1). You can see some more information on RecyclerView on the Xamarin documentation website [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/recyclerview/).

When in doubt, you can always check the [Android API documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/GridLayoutManager.html).

Comment: I have added now... it was Crosslight.xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView.